# What is the longest off-road portion of the East Coast Greenway as of 2018?

Tags: touring, travelling

The East Coast Greenway nominally stretches from Maine to Florida. But a lot of it has yet to be built. That means a lot of the route is actually still on-road cycling.

What is the current longest paved stretch that one can cover without riding on a road*?

*excepting perpendicular crossings of course

Comment: Interesting question, but many of the off-road sections of the ECG are crushed limestone or similar materials, rather than paved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the "Historic Coastal Route" alternate there is a 51 mile (82 km) separated paved cycle path, the [Virginia Capital Trail](https://www.virginiacapitaltrail.org/). I had the privilege of riding this last year on my ECG tour.

[image: Virginia Capital Trail Mile 51.2]

One end of the path is near downtown Richmond on the riverfront.

[image: Virginia Capital Trail direction finder]

It remains off road for the next 51 miles or so, though it does cross the highway several times.

[image: Virginia Capital Trail Mile 34]

[image: Virginia Capital Trail Mile 17]

The other end is at the Jamestown Settlement, a few hundred meters from the Jamestown Ferry (also part of the ECG route).

[image: Virginia Capital Trail Mile 0]

---

When complete, the [Florida Keys Overseas Heritage Trail](https://www.floridastateparks.org/trail/Florida-Keys) will be longer than this, at 106 miles (171 km). But currently its longest off road segment is 34 miles (55 km).

The [M-Path Trail](https://www.traillink.com/trail/m-path-trail-/) and [South Dade Trail](https://www.traillink.com/trail/south-dade-trail/), in Miami-Dade County, Florida, connect to each other to form a continuous 30.3 miles (48.8 km) leading out of Miami towards Homestead.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to cycle this region last year due to Hurricane Irma. I look forward to going sometime soon.

---

If you're considering an ECG tour, keep in mind that even at this early stage, many of the on-road route sections have good hard shoulders or cycle lanes or both.

[image: Elkton, Maryland ECG]

Most of the places where there aren't hard shoulders or cycle lanes are on very quiet rural roads.

[image: Rural Virginia ECG]

But it is still helpful to have some experience with road riding. There are a few places where you may need to take a full lane with cars going 60mph (100 km/h), such as [this 2 mile (3 km) bit](https://map.greenway.org/?loc=14,36.52778,-76.36356) just across the border in North Carolina.

[image: North Carolina border ECG route]

Comment: Hooray for bike route signs that give distances. Over here (at least, within towns) they tend to give times, which is completely useless because I've no idea how fast they think cyclists cycle.

Comment: I don't know what your town councils are using, but Google apparently uses a 12mph average to calculate cycling times. I find this to be just a bit high for fully loaded cycle touring.

Comment: What a comprehensive answer! Thanks for all the pictures and details.